# Equivalent to cpp const methods in typescript

Tags: typescript, methods

I'm trying to find the equivalent to cpp's `const` methods in typescript<sup>1</sup>

```js
class Person {
  constructor(private readonly id: string, private age: number){}
  public /* const     */bigEnough() { return this.age >= 18; }
  public /* mutatable */celebrateBirthday() { this.age += 1; }
}
```

That is, methods that *can not* mutate the data members of their class.

---

<sup>1</sup> motivation: enforce behavior of *subclasses*, and straightforward self documentating code.

Comment: This is not a thing in Typescript. This features simply doesn't exist. You could maybe declare those methods with a `this` parameter of `this: Readonly<Person>`, but that won't subclass well and will only work for public properties. https://tsplay.dev/wjeM6W